# When will the dynamic memory be destroyed in a C++ map with unique ptr as value?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a `std::map`:

```
std::map<uint64_t, unique_ptr<struct stats>> profile_stats;
```

And my insert and delete functions look like this:

Insert:

```
WriteLock(profile_stats_lock);
profile_stats_it it = profile_stats.find(id);
if (it == profile_stats.end()) {
   profile_stats[id] = unique_ptr<stats>(new stats());
}
```

Delete:

```
WriteLock(profile_stats_lock);
profile_stats_it it = profile_stats.find(id);
if (it != profile_stats.end()) {
   profile_stats.erase(it);
}
```

Will the dynamic memory for `new stats()` allocated during insert be destroyed when the iterator is erased in the delete function? Or should I do something to explicitly delete the dynamic memory being pointed to by the unique pointer?

Comment: You don't need to use the `struct` keyword when naming a struct in C++. That's required by C only. Just `unique_ptr<stats>` is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will the dynamic memory for `new stats()` allocated during insert be destroyed when the iterator is erased in the delete function?

Yes.  That is the whole point of using `unique_ptr` in the first place.  It will free the `new`'ed memory for you when itself is destroyed, such as when it is removed from the `std::map` for any reason.

---

On a side note, in your insert function, you should use `std::map::emplace()`  (or `std::map::insert()`) instead of using `std::map::operator[]`.  `operator[]` searches the map for a matching key and then inserts a new element if the key is not found.  Since you already know from `find()` that the `id` will not be found, performing a 2nd scan of the entire map again is just wasted overhead.

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args && ... args) {
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}

...

WriteLock(profile_stats_lock);
profile_stats_it it = profile_stats.find(id);
if (it == profile_stats.end()) {
   profile_stats.emplace(id, make_unique<stats>());
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't mind wasting a potentially unused `new`, you can simply omit `find()` as `emplace()` (and `insert()`) will not perform an insertion if the key already exists:

```
WriteLock(profile_stats_lock);
profile_stats.emplace(id, make_unique<stats>());
```

Or, you can skip allocating the `stats` unless a new map element is actually inserted:

```
WriteLock(profile_stats_lock);
auto res = profile_stats.emplace(id, nullptr);
if (res.second)
    res.first->second = make_unique<stats>();
```

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of using smart pointers like this is because it *is* all automatic.

> Will the dynamic memory for `new stats()` allocated during insert be destroyed when the iterator is erased in the delete function?

Yes.  Any such pointers remaining in the map will also be freed correctly when the map itself is destroyed.

Also note that `std::make_unique<stats>()` is safer than `std::unique_ptr<stats>(new stats())`, and also only requires the type to be named once.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I cannot use c++14 that's why I cannot use make_unique.

Comment: @VenkatKrishnan You can implement it yourself pretty easily. `template <typename T, typename... Args> std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args && ... args) { return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)); }`